# VBA If then statement Multiple filters

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am working on a spreadsheet where I want to exclude any entries that have a zero under the hours worked field, except for those entries that have a code beginning with a "S". How do I accomplish this task? My plan was to use an if then statement but I haven't been able to get it too work

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for posting a question. Please include a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as part of you post. In addition to helping us see your data, this will show us what you've tried to do so far.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for posting a question. Please include a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as part of you post. In addition to helping us see your data, this will show us what you've tried to do so far. Also, asking us "Does any have an example of this they could show me?" is asking for an off site resource. Please show us what you've tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your question didn't make much sense.

You can use

```
InStr( [start], string, substring, [compare] )
```

to fin if one string is in another.